# Azure Self Service Password Reset - redirect on final step after successful password change

Tags: azure, redirect, passwords, reset

We are hitting a bit of a brick wall with this one – if you go to this article and look at the final screenshot, it includes a message 'To sign in with your new password, click here' and the click here must be configurable:

http://www.rebeladmin.com/2019/02/step-step-guide-using-microsoft-authenticator-app-public-preview-reset-azure-ad-user-password/

Can anyone tell us how to config that link on the success page please?  Otherwise, the user will have to manually enter in the URL to login which seems a bit bonk.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you please put more details of what you have done and where you are stuck. I am not sure where to help you based on this question at this point.

Answer (score 0):

That option isn't configurable for SSPR and it's most likely by design for security reasons.

I don't see any legitimate use case for configuring this URL either.  When the user clicks the link they should be taken to login.microsoftonline.com and after successfully logging in will be taken to the original site the user was trying to access since it's embedded in all links across the SSPR experience by means of query parameters.